# Facebook IOS SDK optional permissions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

My IOS app ask the user for "publish_stream" permission, the problem is when the optional permissions screen appears and user click Allow non the facebook sdk does not take this action because the app can post on user wall. when i check the setting on facebook account i see that "post in your behalf" permission exists. here is the code:

```
NSArray* permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"publish_stream", @"email",
                               @"user_birthday",@"user_relationships", @"user_location", @"user_hometown", nil];
```

---

```
-(void)loginToFacebook
{
    [facebook authorize:permissions];}
```

---

```
- (void)fbDidLogin 
{
    NSLog(@"did login");

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebookAgent accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebookAgent expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];

[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/permissions" andDelegate:self];
}
```

---

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result
{
    NSLog(@"%@",result);
}
```

if the user click Allow non in optional permissions page the result in request:didLoad method is:

```
{
    data =     (
                {
            "create_note" = 1;
            email = 1;
            installed = 1;
            "photo_upload" = 1;
            "publish_actions" = 1;
            "publish_stream" = 1;
            "share_item" = 1;
            "status_update" = 1;
            "user_birthday" = 1;
            "user_hometown" = 1;
            "user_location" = 1;
            "user_relationships" = 1;
            "video_upload" = 1;
        }
    );
}
```

and this is the post code:

```
-(void)publishToFacebook
{   
    NSDictionary* attachment = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"Name", @"name",
                                @"Caption", @"caption",
                                @"Message", @"message",
                                @"http://url...", @"link", 
                                @"http://imageUrl...", @"picture", nil];


    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:attachment];


    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" 
                            andParams:params
                        andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                            andDelegate:self];
}
```

Comment: *sidenote*: the above code is no longer valid for Facebook iOS SDK 3.x

Answer (score 0):

THanks for this post. A bug is filed related to this at 
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/111727002307769
and it is being assigned. As soon as we have it fixed, you should be good to go. Thanks for your patience.